# How to make a random color with Swift

Tags: swift, random, colors, uicolor, func

How I can make a random color function using Swift?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(20)
    var randomColor = arc4random()

    //Color Background randomly
    func colorBackground() {

        // TODO: set a random color
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    }
}
```

Answer (score 223):

You're going to need a function to produce random `CGFloat`s in the range 0 to 1:

```
extension CGFloat {
    static func random() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}
```

Then you can use this to create a random colour:

```
extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
           red:   .random(),
           green: .random(),
           blue:  .random(),
           alpha: 1.0
        )
    }
}
```

If you wanted a random alpha, just create another random number for that too.

You can now assign your view's background colour like so:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .random()
```

Comment: `static func random() -> CGFloat` is useless outside of `static func random() -> UIColor` so you can declare the first method inside the second one

Comment: In recent versions of Swift, most (all?) scalar types have a `random(in:)` function that returns random values. For CGFloat that function is `static func random(in range: ClosedRange<CGFloat>) -> CGFloat` So you can just use `.random(in: 0...1)`. No need for your custom `random()` function.

Answer (score 130):

#### For Swift 4.2

```
extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: .random(in: 0...1),
            green: .random(in: 0...1),
            blue: .random(in: 0...1),
            alpha: 1.0
        )
    }
}
```

#### For Swift 3 and above:

```
extension CGFloat {
    static var random: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random, green: .random, blue: .random, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
let myColor: UIColor = .random
```

Answer (score 37):

Make a function to generate random color:

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {
     //Generate between 0 to 1
     let red:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())   
     let green:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48()) 
     let blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())  

     return UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Now, you can call this function whenever you need random color.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()
```

Comment: here if any body want to know more about CGFLoat https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat

Answer (score 37):

For random solid colors you can use UIColor HSB initializer and randomize only the hue:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return .init(hue: .random(in: 0...1), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

---

```
let color1: UIColor = .random
let color2: UIColor = .random
let color3: UIColor = .random
let color4: UIColor = .random
let color5: UIColor = .random
```

---

[image]

Comment: Check your screenshot: what was the probability to get your perfect yellow (second result)?

Comment: You can fine tune the odds using integers and determining now many steps you want in the hue range

Comment: I believe the odds were about 1 out of 6000 for this yellow: there aren't any rounding to Int8 being done, so you had 1 chance of 1000 to get a float smaller than 0.0005 or bigger than 0.9995. And then there are 6 edges possibles (0 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 1 1, 1 0 0, 1 0 1, 1 1 0).

Comment: I think you are right I came up with the odds of 1 out of 6666 to generate a float in range `0.16659 ... 0.16674`

Answer (score 28):

### SwiftUI - Swift 5

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    static var random: Color {
        return Color(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                     green: .random(in: 0...1),
                     blue: .random(in: 0...1))
    }
}
```

### Usage:

`let randomColor: Color = .random`

Answer (score 14):

With **Swift 4.2**, you can simplify this by using the new random functions which have been added:

```
extension UIColor {
  static func random () -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
      red: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
      green: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
      blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
      alpha: 1.0)
  }
}
```

There are more details [here](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-4-2-random-changes-wwdc-2018/).

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4.2**

I'm adding this answer because it uses a different approach, and because many of the previous answers requires additional syntactic sugar, which in my opinion shouldn't be preferred. Vanilla Swift for the win.

```
extension UIColor {
    /**
     * Returns random color
     * ## Examples: 
     * self.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
     */
    static var random: UIColor {
        let r:CGFloat  = .random(in: 0...1)
        let g:CGFloat  = .random(in: 0...1)
        let b:CGFloat  = .random(in: 0...1)
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.2** Extension

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    convenience init(rgb: Int) {
        self.init(
            red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
            green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
            blue: rgb & 0xFF
        )
    }

    static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(rgb: Int(CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * 0xFFFFFF))
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
let color = UIColor.random()
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5.1**

Make This function and generate Random color.

e.g. `view.backgroundColor = random()`

```
func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                       green: .random(in: 0...1),
                       blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an extension with an inline function to generate randoms

```
extension UIColor {
    static func random() -> UIColor {

        func random() -> CGFloat { return .random(in:0...1) }

        return UIColor(red:   random(),
                       green: random(),
                       blue:  random(),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.8.1** Extension

```
extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return .init(red: .random(in: 0...1), green: .random(in: 0...1), blue: .random(in: 0...1), alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let randomColor = UIColor.random
print(randomColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func anotherGetRandomColor()->UIColor{

    let newRed   = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))/255.0
    let newGreen = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))/255.0
    let newBlue  = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))/255.0

    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(newRed), green: CGFloat(newGreen), blue: CGFloat(newBlue), alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: The entropy of this code is 255*255*255, which could be weak. Better generate floating values instead of small integers. On top of that, `arc4random_uniform(255)` will only give values from 0 to 254, so you're biased toward darker colors.

Comment: @Cœur besides that his division is flawed because he initialized CGFloat after dividing a value in the range 0...254 / 255 which would cause to zero all results

Answer (score 0):

## ✅ Persisted Random Color

It's easy to generate random colors when you know colors are made from numbers. So just pass in random values from `0.0` to `1.0`. But many times you actually wanted to keep the random color without actually storing it.

Here is how you can generate random colors based on a seed (like for example the `userID`) which always be the same:

```
/// - Note: Make it `Color` for SwiftUI
extension UIColor {
    static func random(seed: Int) -> Self {
        var generator = RandomNumberGenerator(seed: seed)

        return .init(
            red: .random(in: (0...1), using: &generator),
            green: .random(in: (0...1), using: &generator),
            blue: .random(in: (0...1), using: &generator)
            , alpha: 1 // Remove this line for the `SwiftUI.Color`
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the random number generator behind this:

```
struct RandomNumberGenerator: Swift.RandomNumberGenerator {
    init(seed: Int) { srand48(seed) }
    func next() -> UInt64 { UInt64(drand48() * Double(UInt64.max)) }
}
```

###### SwiftUI Example:

The following will always be the same and doesn't change on each run (nor each preview).

[image: SwiftUI sample]
<sub>Note that you can use the random generator in a way that matches your needs</sub>