# Swift UI LazyVStack with nested VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, lazyvstack, swiftui-vstack

I'm experiencing this issue and not user if it's a swift ui bug or expected behaviour. Could not find something related to this online.

Given this view

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
      LazyVStack {
        // has has many items so you can scroll
        ForEach((0...40), id: \.self) { index in
          MyView()  // (1)
          VStack {
            MyView()  // (2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where `MyView` is a simple view

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.random // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43365841/901249
    }
}
```

When I scroll down *(so the `MyView (2)` is off screen)* and then back up, `MyView (2)` has a different color, while `MyView (1)` remains unchanged the same.

If I add `let _ = Self._printChanges()` in `MyView` `body`, `MyView (2)` will print

```
MyView: @self changed
```

This happens no matter what kind of stack it is (HStack, ZStack, VStack) as long as it's in a LazyXStack it has this behaviour.

Why does a nested XStack inside a LazyYStack recreates it's content?

Comment: Does `2` have the same color as the other view that was shown after `2` moved out of the screen? That could mean is not recreating but "recycling", why don't you add an initializer for `MyView` and add a `print` there, if you pass the `index` then you can make sure is happening and when.

Comment: Because a Lazy stack unloads its content when it is off screen. When it is reloaded, it re-evaluates the body and you’ve explicitly said random, so there’s no memory of what the color was in first evaluation

Comment: @jnpdx It makes sense, but why doesn't the rule apply to `MyView()  // (1)` ? 
`(1)` color doesn't change, only the views that are added in a VStack/HStack/ZStack do. 
The view and it's state are recreated.

I find this very odd, and extremely unintuitive.

Comment: What is so surprising about this? Everytime you scroll back up and down again you're reinitialising new ```MyView()```view cells with a new random color.

Comment: @devdchaudhary The surprising thing to me is that the view outside the VStack doesn't behave the same as the view inside the VStack.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly an interesting case. I tried out a number of variations in an attempt to get a better understanding. Here are some observations:

- If a `VStack` is used instead of `LazyVStack` then the colors are preserved. This is perhaps no big surprise because you would expect a `VStack` to load the nested content once and then hold it in memory.
- If you change the implementation of `MyView` to this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    let color = Color.random
    var body: some View {
        color
    }
}
```

...then you find that the colors are preserved.  So it is not the view instances themselves which are being discarded, but the views returned by their `body` property.

- To confirm the last point, you can add an initializor to `MyView` and print the index (as was suggested in one of the comments to the question):

```swift
init(_ index: Int, _ item: Int) {
    print("creating \(index)-\(item)")
}
```

This shows that the views are only created once.

- I added some buttons to make scrolling quicker:

```swift
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        LazyVStack {
            Button("Scroll to bottom") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 10)) { proxy.scrollTo(-2) }
            }
            .id(-1)
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

            // has has many items so you can scroll
            ForEach((0...40), id: \.self) { index in
                MyView(index, 1)  // (1)
                VStack {
                    MyView(index, 2)  // (2)
                }
            }
            Button("Scroll to top") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 10)) { proxy.scrollTo(-1) }
            }
            .id(-2)
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried steadily doubling the number of rows, trying to see if there was a point at which the views were being re-created (meaning, they were no longer being cached). I thought that this might cause the colors of view `1` to change, sooner or later. If you scroll up and down many times then what you find is that it steadily fills the gaps of the rows that were not created the first time, but it is difficult to tell if any rows are actually being re-created. My guess is that the cache is optimized, so anything that was recently shown is not likely to be discarded. I certainly wasn't able to see any changes in the rows I was monitoring.

**Conclusions from all of this**

It is not surprising to find that the content of the `LazyVStack` is being discarded when it is out of view. What is perhaps more surprising, is that all cases of view `1` preserve their color. But the experiments above have shown that in fact it is only the body of the nested views (view `2`) that are being discarded, probably as a memory optimization. If the random color is captured in `init` instead of being chosen in `body` then these views do not change color either.

Comment: The `body` and it's state.
If you just define `@State private var someState`, in `MyView`, and add `let _ = Self._printChanges()` in the body, you will see `MyView: @self, @identity, _someState changed.`
It is curious if you pass the random color on MyView init, it is stored and not recomputed.

Comment: Good analysis, except one misconception: a SwiftUI view _is not_ a view. Well, if the latter `view` is the thing that renders some data. So, a SwiftUI view is a _means_ to create and modify the underlying view. In the c-tor of the SwiftUI view you assume, when it is called, it will "create" a view. This is not true. This will only create a view, if the "identity" of the SwiftUI view has not yet an underlying view. Otherwise, it will modify the existing underlying view with the data you set up in the SwiftUI view.

Comment: It would be so nice if SwiftUI were open-sourced so we could just read it and understand it instead of having to reverse-engineer the framework to understand why it behaves a particular way

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely sure this is expected behaviour.

`LazyVStack` just know how much blocks inside of it do you have and which size of each block. (to know size of `LazyVStack`). But `LazyVStack` does not render views inside of it before user will see it.

### That's why it called LAZY.

So when `LazyVStack` think that user must to see some view soon - it will render it. On each time when it will render block of

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.random // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43365841/901249
    }
}
```

this block will generate the new one color. On EACH RE-RENDER!

In the same time each block that user must not see soon is removed from memory. So you loose pre-rendered information and it will be re-generated on another display of view.

So if you want to have static colors set inside of `LazyVStack` - you need to create array of random colors.

Or in another case you need to use `VStack` instead of `LazyVStack` . It's renders ALL children views, that's why all colors will be static due to scroll process on any distance.

But you need to understand that colors can be the new one on each View refresh in case of change view's `id`. This means that even `VStack` will not guarantee you that this set of colors will be the same after view refresh.

That's why you need to use pre-initiated array of random colors for this in any case - will you use `VStack` or will you use `LazyVStack`.